# Change dropdrown length select to buttons - jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, datatables

Is it possible to change the Datatables drop down length select to buttons representing [10][25][50][100]. So that if we click on the number we can change the length of the table with pagination.

I tried many manipulations which are given in 
http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/ but of no use please suggest me how to change the drop down to buttons

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature plug-in for DataTables that provides that ability here:
        https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/tree/master/features/lengthLinks.
If we plug the dataTables.lengthLinks.js its working fine. and the implementation is clearly given in js.